# change ip address for my computer every x times python windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, networking, web-scraping

i use python 3.6 and windows 7
i try to use wmi but not working every time i try to change the ip address
no connection happen with the net
and give me this error DHCP is not enabled for local area connection
my code to change the ip address :

```
def change_ip_address():

nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)
try:
    nic=nic_configs[0]
except:
    raise Exception("error in change ip address")
ip= u'192.168.43.99'
subnetmask=u'255.255.0.0'
gateway = u'15.0.0.254'
nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
```

is there any library for windows to do that

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your local network has a [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server. This server assigns your PC an IP adress, which it then routes packets to. If you change the IP adress of the nic in your PC, then your PC and the DHCP server no longer agree on the IP adress that you are using. Consequently, packets cannot be routed to your PC, and the PC will report that you do not have an internet connection. There [are](https://superuser.com/questions/487607/how-to-request-a-specific-ip-address-from-dhcp-server) ways to negotiate a specific IP, assuming that it is available.

If your local network does not have a DHCP server, then there is a server-side configuration that specifies a static IP adress for your MAC adress or the ethernet wall port. In this case, the change must be made on that server.

What you are currently doing, is similar to making up an adress and putting that on your business card and front door. If you were to use a made-up adress, would you expect your mail to arrive to the right door? You would need to at least talk to some civil servant or government official to get it done.

Comment: i use my pc on home we have tp-link router i think in this case the router assign local ip address for my pc and the router talk to the internet with global ip in this case what can i do to change my ip

Comment: Which IP?
Local IP: Read your router's manual, and assign yourself a static IP (preferably outside the range of IP's handed out by the router's DHCP server) in your router's admin panel. Then reboot the router.
Global IP: Call your ISP and ask nicely.

Comment: in egypt in general you don't have static ip when you turn off the router and turn on back then you have new ip